# Import Error on Dates (Import from oracle 10g to sql server 2005)

Tags: sql-server-2005, import

I've been trying to import a table from oracle 10g into SQL Server 2005 using the task import wizard and i keep getting this error:

```
- Copying to [PersonDB].[PEOPLE] (Error)
Messages
Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Native Client"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Invalid character value for cast specification".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc020901c: Data Flow Task: There was an error with input column "EFFCHGDT" (416) on input "Destination Input" (269). The column status returned was: "Conversion failed because the data value overflowed the specified type.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0209029: Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_INDUCEDTRANSFORMFAILUREONERROR.  The "input "Destination Input" (269)" failed because error code 0xC020907A occurred, and the error row disposition on "input "Destination Input" (269)" specifies failure on error. An error occurred on the specified object of the specified component.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047022: Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PROCESSINPUTFAILED.  The ProcessInput method on component "Destination - PEOPLE" (256) failed with error code 0xC0209029. The identified component returned an error from the ProcessInput method. The error is specific to the component, but the error is fatal and will cause the Data Flow task to stop running.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047021: Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_THREADFAILED.  Thread "WorkThread0" has exited with error code 0xC0209029.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the thread has exited.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc02020c4: Data Flow Task: The attempt to add a row to the Data Flow task buffer failed with error code 0xC0047020.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047038: Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_PRIMEOUTPUTFAILED.  The PrimeOutput method on component "Source - PEOPLE" (1) returned error code 0xC02020C4.  The component returned a failure code when the pipeline engine called PrimeOutput(). The meaning of the failure code is defined by the component, but the error is fatal and the pipeline stopped executing.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information about the failure.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)

Error 0xc0047021: Data Flow Task: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_THREADFAILED.  Thread "SourceThread0" has exited with error code 0xC0047038.  There may be error messages posted before this with more information on why the thread has exited.
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)
```

I'm guessing it has to do with the Date Field in oracle.
I ran the same process on sql server express   2008 and it imported without any errors.

Does anyone know how i can get the import process to work with sql server 2005?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably are using the new date dataypes in sql server 2008 which do not exist in 2005 like datetime2. in sql server 2005 the datetime datatype only goes back to January 1, 1753

so you either have to store them as string in 2005, or change it to 1/1/1900

or

use sql 2008 with the correct data types

take a look at this, as you can see the first date is not valid

```
select isdate('15000101'), isdate('17530101'),isdate('20080101')
```